# How generate random ball in a specific space with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I created a tikz picture as following :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw[blue,thin,->,dashed] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5)node[blue,right]{\scriptsize $y_{RP}$};
\draw[blue,thin,->,dashed] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0)node[blue,below]{\scriptsize $x_{RP}$};
\draw[blue,dashed] (-0.6,0) circle (1);
\draw[blue,dashed] (0.6,0) circle (1);
\fill[inner color=black,outer color=green,dashed] (0.1,0.1) circle (0.05);
\draw[red,rotate=10] (0,0) ellipse (0.3cm and 0.6cm);
\draw[red,->,rotate=10] (0,0) -- (2.5,0)node[above,rotate=10,red]{\scriptsize $x_{PP}$};
\draw[red,->,rotate=10] (0,0) -- (0,1.5)node[left,rotate=10,red]{\scriptsize $y_{PP}$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Schematicely reproduce by :
[image: picture]

I want put a number (I don't know the exact number but maybe 10-15) balls in a random place to fill the red ellipse. I know that I can do a ball with `\usetikzlibrary{shapes}` and `\shade [ball color=green] (0.1,0.1) circle [radius=0.05cm];` for example but I put just here a circle for example.

Can we do that with tikz ? How we can do that ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really just a question of what you need to do to place a point randomly inside the ellipse. If you use a parametric equation then you should choose a random angle and random lengths along the two axes and then you have a random point.

**Edit**

In fact, as there are only two coordinates it is better to choose polar coordinates randomly and then rescale to the ellipse.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, shapes}

\newcommand\RandomPointInEllipse[3]{% \RandomPointInEllipse[a][b][rotation]
  % parametrically, the ellipse is (a\cos u, b\sin u), so randomly
  % choose polar coordinates (r,u) and then rescale to ellipse
  \pgfmathsetmacro\uRnd{random(0,360)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\rRnd{random}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\aRnd{#1*\rRnd*cos(\uRnd)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\bRnd{#2*\rRnd*sin(\uRnd)}
  \shade [ball color=green, rotate=#3] (\aRnd,\bRnd) circle [radius=0.05cm];
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \draw[blue,thin,->,dashed] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5)node[blue,right]{\scriptsize $y_{RP}$};
    \draw[blue,thin,->,dashed] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0)node[blue,below]{\scriptsize $x_{RP}$};
    \draw[blue,dashed] (-0.6,0) circle (1);
    \draw[blue,dashed] (0.6,0) circle (1);
    \fill[inner color=black,outer color=green,dashed] (0.1,0.1) circle (0.05);
    \draw[red,rotate=10] (0,0) ellipse (0.3cm and 0.6cm);
    \draw[red,->,rotate=10] (0,0) -- (2.5,0)node[above,rotate=10,red]{\scriptsize $x_{PP}$};
    \draw[red,->,rotate=10] (0,0) -- (0,1.5)node[left,rotate=10,red]{\scriptsize $y_{PP}$};
    \foreach \ball in {1,...,10} { \RandomPointInEllipse{0.3}{0.6}{10}}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a very proper solution, I like it, because I want ball inside and not on the ellipse, I just changed  `\pgfmathsetmacro\aRnd{0.3*rand*cos(\uRnd)}` and  `\pgfmathsetmacro\bRnd{0.6*rand*sin(\uRnd)}`
 by `\pgfmathsetmacro\aRnd{0.25*rand*cos(\uRnd)}` and `\pgfmathsetmacro\bRnd{0.55*rand*sin(\uRnd)}`

Comment: @G.Sophys Actually, I realised that I was over doing it as there are only two degrees of freedom. It is better to randomly choose polar coordinates inside the unit circle and then rescale to the ellipse.

Answer (score 6):

Something like that could help...

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ]
        \begin{scope}[rotate=10]
              \draw[red] (0,0) ellipse (0.3 and 0.6);
              \foreach \x in {1,...,10} {
                  \shade [ball color=green] (0.25*rand, 0.55*rand) circle [radius=0.05];
               }
        \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

...the tricky part is the mix of coordinates in absolute values and the `x` and `y` of tikz.

[image]

Comment: I did know the `rand` variables but it works well, when I try with more balls (20), I saw one ball outside the ellispe, I changed `0.25*rand, 0.55*rand` by `0.2*rand, 0.5*rand`. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 4):

with use of `clip`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,
        N/.style   = {rotate=#1, font=\scriptsize},
        N/.default = 0,
        L/.style   = {blue, dashed, ->}
                    ]
\draw[L,thin]   ( 0.0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[N,right] {$y_{RP}$};
\draw[L,thin]   (-2.5, 0.0) -- (2.5,0) node[N,below] {$x_{RP}$};
\draw[blue]     (-0.6, 0.0) circle (1);
\draw[blue]     ( 0.6, 0.0) circle (1);
\draw[red,->,rotate=10] (0,0) -- (2.5,0) node[N=10,above] {$x_{PP}$};
\draw[red,->,rotate=10] (0,0) -- (0,1.5) node[N=10,left]  {$y_{PP}$};
%
\begin{scope}[red,rotate=10]
\draw[clip] (0,0) ellipse (0.3cm and 0.6cm);
\foreach \i in {1,...,30}
\fill[ball color=green] (rand*360:rand/2) circle (0.25mm);
\end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) using a `transformation` to keep the ellipse within the overlap of the two circles, and to place the balls neatly inside it.
[image: Balls in an ellipse]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

vardef ball(expr r, light_angle, base_shade, white_shade, rim_shade) = 
    save c; path c, c'; 
    c = fullcircle scaled 2r;
    c' = fullcircle scaled 1/32 r shifted 1/2(r,0) rotated light_angle;
    image(
        for s=0 step 1/64 until 1:
            fill interpath(s, c, c') withcolor s[base_shade, white_shade];
        endfor
        draw c withcolor rim_shade;
    )
enddef;

beginfig(1);

    numeric u; u = 42;

    path xx, xx', yy, yy', C, D, E;

    xx = (left -- right) scaled 4u;
    yy = (down -- up) scaled 3u;
    xx' = subpath (1/2, 1) of xx rotated 12;
    yy' = subpath (1/2, 1) of yy rotated 12;

    numeric d; d = .8u;
    C = fullcircle scaled 4u shifted (d,0);
    D = fullcircle scaled 4u shifted (-d,0);

    z0 = xx' intersectionpoint D;
    z1 = yy' intersectionpoint C;

    transform T; 
    origin transformed T = origin;
    right transformed T = 3/4 z0;
    up transformed T = 3/4 z1;
    E = fullcircle scaled 2 transformed T;

    drawoptions(dashed withdots scaled 1/2 withcolor 2/3 blue);
    drawarrow xx; drawarrow yy; draw C; draw D;
    label.rt("$x_{RP}$", point 1 of xx);
    label.urt("$y_{RP}$", point 1 of yy);

    drawoptions(withcolor 3/4 red);
    drawarrow xx'; drawarrow yy'; draw E;
    label.urt("$x_{PP}$", point 1 of xx');
    label.ulft("$y_{PP}$", point 1 of yy');

    drawoptions();

    picture b; b = ball(2.4, 135, 3/4 green, red+green, 3/4 green);

    for i=1 upto 20:
        draw b shifted (uniformdeviate 7/8 * dir uniformdeviate 360 transformed T);
    endfor

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

This is wrapped up in [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en) so compile with `lualatex`, or adapt for plain MP or for [`gmp`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/gmp?lang=en).